# In custom filter component Dropdown is overlapping under ag-grid angular

Tags: filter, multi-select, ag-grid-angular

I have created my multi-select filter custom component and I have assigned that component to the floatingFilterComponent in column definition. Dropdown is opening on toggle when click on dropdown icon, but that dropdown list is opening under the grid. The grid is overlapping it. Tried to solve it with position:absolute and z-index but it is not working for me. I am able to figure out the issue exactly , that which css needs to change.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INNXg.png)

Comment: The question is missing some code.